# Two-Way Communication Between Applications Using UDP

Tags: c#, .net, udp, udpclient

I've done this already using TCP/IP. I am now trying to do this using UDP. These applications are both being run on the same host. So both the client/server are sending/receiving on the 127.0.0.1:5000. The problem is that they are receiving the messages intended for the other application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't test these UDP applications from the same machine. There is no concept of a connection in UDP, so there is no way to distinguish here.

Comment: Darn. OK, so UDP can be used on the same host for one-way communication only. TCP can be used for two way on the same host. Both can be used across a network for both one and two-way communication.

Comment: You could use udp two-ways if each "side" had it's own, unique port. But that would not lend itself well to testing your application without creating other complexities.

Comment: you could simulate another machine by adding a 2nd IPAddress to your machine, and bind your "Server" to IPAddress 1:5000 and your Client to IPAddress 2:5000 then when you send just manage which IP you are simulating

Comment: @Paul Good point; you might not even need a second IP; if you bind carefully, you could use the real IP for one, and the localhost IP for the other.